# How to get the URL for which downloadBegin() event is fired?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, iwebbrowser2

I am attempting to create a custom web browser based on the WPF Web browser control. I have implemented the `IWebBrowser2 com` interface and implemented the handlers for `Navigating()`, `NavigatedTo()` and `LoadCompleted()` events.
But these event callbacks are fired only once for the top level page. 
Now suppose a page has some java script , css and image files in it; the browser issues separate HTTP requests to download these files. We would like to capture the individual HTTP request events. For example, if the structure of the HTML page is

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="img1.bmp"/>
    <imp src="img2.bmp"/>
  </body>  
</html>
```

I would like to capture the individual download times for img1.bmp and img2.bmp. Could someone please suggest a way to achieve this?

Meanwhile I found that downloadbegin() event of `DWebBrowserEvents_Event` is fired for these request for image etc, but I can't get the URL from which it is downloading, as the handler takes void as parameter.

So is there any way I can get the URL corresponding because there is event that is downloadComplete which is fired when download is complete. So by that I can accomplish that way.

But I have to solve the above image rendering time. I am stuck badly. Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

i dont have deep knowledge about this classes but i did a little reading.
in mdsn they say about the downloadbegin() event:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136556(v=vs.85).aspx

> This event is fired **shortly after** the DWebBrowserEvents::BeforeNavigate event or the DWebBrowserEvents2::BeforeNavigate2 event, unless the navigation is canceled. Any animation or "busy" indication that the container must display should be connected to this event.

and when i checked the BeforeNavigate i saw that it has a url in its paramaters i found this (not msdn but its only logical that itll have a url) http://blog.yezhucn.com/progie/222647_beforenavigate.htm

> void BeforeNavigate(
>       IDispatch *pDisp,
>       VARIANT *&url,
>       VARIANT *&Flags,
>       VARIANT *&TargetFrameName,
>       VARIANT *&PostData,
>       VARIANT *&Headers,
>       VARIANT_BOOL *&Cancel
>   );

so if you will always have a BeforeNavigate event you can use its url and check the next download complete event thats connected to the DownloadBegin event. 
my guess is that for each download it makes a BeforeNavigate event but i wont know because i cant try (no code to check it on) but i hope itll help.

Comment: BeforeNavigate is only called once, not once for each file downloaded for the page.